# I don't understand. I'm trying to create the first table for a database in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

It's telling me to provide a FK and a table reference when there is no FK in the table, nor a relevant table to reference.

[image: Here's the SS]

Comment: All I can say is that those - who live by the GUI, die by the GUI. Create table by writing your own script in SQL*Plus (or any appropriate tool, Apex' SQL Workshop included) and you'll do exactly what you want, not what GUI **thinks** you'd want to do.

Comment: I've just done exactly that, so much better haha, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define a FK. Just scroll down and click Next.

[image]

Comment: When I clicked next it came up with errors saying I needed to select a FK and a reference from another table. I scripted a table anyway so it's all good now